# View is dismissing to the wrong view with tabbar and navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Ok so here is a picture of my basic setup  [image: storyboard]

Now this may not be the best way to set it all up but I did what I could with the knowledge I had to get the effect I wanted. Now my problem is originates in view 1 but only happens if you do this: Start at the menu click view 2,3 or 4 to go to that view then go to view 1 using the tabbar button now at this screen you would click the get pictures button which has the code below in its viewcontroller to show the image picker. Now the problem comes is if you go back at this point it takes you to the tabbarview that you clicked from the menu whether that was 2,3,or 4. It goes back fine if you clicked view 1 from the menu

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.selectedPhotos = [NSMutableArray array];

    __block AGViewController *blockSelf = self;

    ipc = [[AGImagePickerController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    ipc.didFailBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Fail. Error: %@", error);

        if (error == nil) {
            [blockSelf.selectedPhotos removeAllObjects];
            NSLog(@"User has cancelled.");

          [blockSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        } else {

            // We need to wait for the view controller to appear first.
            double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [blockSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];

    };
    ipc.didFinishBlock = ^(NSArray *info) {
        [blockSelf.selectedPhotos setArray:info];

        NSLog(@"Info: %@", info);

        //add all selected photos to the claim

        [blockSelf setClaimPhotos:info];

        [blockSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
    };

}

- (void)openAction:(id)sender
{    
    // Show saved photos on top
    ipc.shouldShowSavedPhotosOnTop = NO;
    ipc.shouldChangeStatusBarStyle = YES;
    ipc.selection = self.selectedPhotos;
    ipc.maximumNumberOfPhotosToBeSelected = 5;

    // Custom toolbar items
    AGIPCToolbarItem *selectAll = [[AGIPCToolbarItem alloc] initWithBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+ Select All" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] andSelectionBlock:^BOOL(NSUInteger index, ALAsset *asset) {
        return YES;
    }];
    AGIPCToolbarItem *flexible = [[AGIPCToolbarItem alloc] initWithBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] andSelectionBlock:nil]; 

    AGIPCToolbarItem *deselectAll = [[AGIPCToolbarItem alloc] initWithBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"- Deselect All" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] andSelectionBlock:^BOOL(NSUInteger index, ALAsset *asset) {
        return NO;
    }];  
    ipc.toolbarItemsForManagingTheSelection = @[selectAll, flexible, flexible, deselectAll];

    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

(the open action is what is tied to the button on the vc)

I really need help on this one as Ive been stuck on this issue all week and have been trying all types of dissmiss view controller ect ect.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have that first Menu view controller? I mean if you are using a tab bar controller for accessing any of those 4 vcs why would you choose it first on this Menu vc?

Comment: @Coche sadly it is necessary to have it. Its whats wanted I just am programming it.

Comment: Can you explain what do these first Menu buttons do? If there is code involved post it also please.

Comment: @Coche Oh wow you got it! I had forgot I had added a class to the tabbar controller that was a setting the selected index. A simmple `    [myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];` on my agviewcontroller fixed my problem!!

Comment: There you go! Glad I've helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due a custom class on the `TabBarController` that was causing an unexpecting behavior with `SelectedIndex` property.